# Node.js / child_process throwing E2BIG

Tags: javascript, linux, node.js, child-process

I have a fairly simple C++ program which only takes one argument that is a Base64 encoded string. I can call the program.

I am now trying to call this program using Node.js' *child_process.spawn()*, but it is throwing an "E2BIG" error when I pass in the same Base64 string.

The Base64 string I am testing with is 305016 bytes in length.

Running `getconf ARG_MAX` on my Linux box returns 2097152.

Why does child_process throw the error?

Comment: Have you seen [What defines the maximum size for a command single argument?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/120642/what-defines-the-maximum-size-for-a-command-single-argument) on unix.SO? It mentions `MAX_ARG_STRLEN` as the maximum length of a string argument.

Comment: Thats useful information to know, but why would it work when running from the command line, but not work using child_process.spawn()?

Comment: `let child = require('child_process').spawn('myprogram');
child.stdin.write(largeBase64String);
child.stdin.end();`
this code is not working?

Comment: @AliRezaRiahi an **argument** is ostensibly a string passed in on the command line, whereas what you are suggesting is to provide input to the program via stdin, that's a different mechanism, and the asker was likely running into command line argument length limitations, whereas stdin is unlimited.  So yes, it's a workaround and ultimately the better approach for large amounts of data, but the question is valid as is and is asking for the *reason*, not a *workaround*.

Answer (score 1):

Try to [strace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strace) it to see if Node.js is making the system call or not - i.e., check is it an internal Node.js limitation or is it the Linux system which is rejecting it.

The `strcpy` used by `libuv` in Node.js can return `E2BIG`.