# Node.js: Passing image as base64 to python with spawn

Tags: node.js, python-3.x, base64, spawn

I'm trying to pass an image as base64 to python for processing using spawn like so:

```
return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
      const pythonProcess = spawn('python',["./python.py", imageDataURI]);
      pythonProcess.stdout.on('data', (response) => {
        resolve(response);
      });
    });
```

But I'm getting `error: Error: spawn E2BIG`
I guess it's too big to pass like this, any alternative ways to pass it to spawn?

Seems related:

[Node / child_process throwing E2BIG](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36251711/node-child-process-throwing-e2big)

Comment: Change the python script to read the image data from its standard input stream `sys.stdin`.  Change the node.js script to write the image data to the Python process by calling `pythonProcess.stdin.write()` followed by `pythonProcess.stdin.end()` to indicate that all of the data has been written.

Comment: Yup, that worked, thanks. In python, read it with `for line in fileinput.input()` (and wrote back out with `sys.stdout.write()` and `sys.stdout.flush()`)

Comment: @ottomeister is there an alternative to end() in case I want to reuse the stream?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to [ottomeister](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1334967/ottomeister)'s answer I did it like this:

In Node:

```
const pythonProcess = spawn('python',["script.py"]);

pythonProcess.stdin.write(data);
pythonProcess.stdin.end();
pythonProcess.stdout.on('data', (result) => {
    handleResult(result);
});
```

In python:

```
import fileinput

for line in fileinput.input():
    input +=line

# Process input

sys.stdout.write(result)
sys.stdout.flush()
```

Comment: I don't get the purpose, you are sending buffer to python from nodejs, & then writting it back to nodejs ? In my case I want to send image buffer to python & do some image processing, without sending it back to nodejs